# Layout problems with iFrame containing PDF

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am using MVC 4 with Bootstrap for a website I am working on.  Rather simple layout, I have the Bootstrap nav bar that stays at top (navbar-fixed-top), then I have a page title, a div with an absolute position and height just bellow the menu.

Then for the page content I have a div, again with absolute pos that has a top set to that it starts just under the page title.  The overflow on the body is set to none and set to auto on the page content.

```
body, html
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.PageTitle
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    color: #fdf4f4;
    background-color: #4266cd;
    border-color: #bce8f1;
}

.Content
{
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This works fine for other pages, but I need to show a monthly flyer (PDF) and want it to fill the content area and allow users to scroll it.  Problem is of course that if I add an iFrame with 100% height, it takes the height of the content div (it's parent) and that's the height of the browser window.  It would be very cool if I could tell it to set the height to 100% - 100px.

I have tried changing the size using jQuery, but have not had any success.

Anyone have some ideas that might help me along the way?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**  I read Akshay Khandelwal's post and created a simple HTML page with the basics if what I am trying to do.  In the process of recreating the problem I had before, I might have found a solution.  It look like the code bellow works.  Not sure if this is a good way to do it or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>PDF View Test</title>

        <style>
            body
            {
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .NavBarTop
            {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 40px;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                background: #778899;
            }

            .PageTitle
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 40px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 60px;
                color: #fdf4f4;
                background-color: #4266cd;
                border-color: #bce8f1;
            }

            .Content
            {
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
            }

            h3
            {
                color: rgb(253, 244, 244);
                display: block;
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 25px;
                font-weight: bold;
                height: 40px;
                line-height: 40px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            h4
            {
                color: rgb(253, 244, 244);
                display: block;
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: bold;
                height: 20px;
                line-height: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            iframe
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="NavBarTop">
            <h4>This is the menu bar.</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="PageTitle">
            <h3>The Page Title</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="Content">
            <iframe src="http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/content-server/pdfs/adobe-ebook-platform-whitepaper.pdf"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated the text with a sample HTML page showing what I am trying to do.  I am going to apply those changes to my project and see if this works.

Comment: Well, I tried it in my main project and it worked.  I had to set the overflow on the content div to be hidden, otherwise it would show scrollbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the question I was asking, even though I am not convinced it's the best way to do it.  For completeness, here's the HTML that will give you a PDF embedded in a web page with scroll bars that only scroll the PDF document and not the page title and menu's.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>PDF View Test</title>

        <style>
            body
            {
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .NavBarTop
            {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 40px;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                background: #778899;
            }

            .PageTitle
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 40px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 60px;
                color: #fdf4f4;
                background-color: #4266cd;
                border-color: #bce8f1;
            }

            .Content
            {
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
            }

            h3
            {
                color: rgb(253, 244, 244);
                display: block;
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 25px;
                font-weight: bold;
                height: 40px;
                line-height: 40px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            h4
            {
                color: rgb(253, 244, 244);
                display: block;
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: bold;
                height: 20px;
                line-height: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            iframe
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="NavBarTop">
            <h4>This is the menu bar.</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="PageTitle">
            <h3>The Page Title</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="Content">
            <iframe src="http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/content-server/pdfs/adobe-ebook-platform-whitepaper.pdf"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems to work great in chrome, safari for desktop(os x). however i experience inability to scroll with touch devices(iphone, android)